# how to get second last character from a string using c#

Tags: c#, string

i want to parse a string to get second last character from a string. Here is what i am trying to parse

```
[XX] G_RIMN_4000+_OLEPHI_700+ [InstalmentScheme 1]
```

From above string i want to get the second last character whether it is single digit or double digit
so e.g `1]` i want `1` or `26]` i want `26`

I tried following approach

```
string input = "[XR] Z_Prem_4000+_Delphi_700+ [InstalmentScheme 1]";

var words = input.Split(' ');
var reqWord = "";
if(words.Length > 1)
   reqWord = words[words.Length-1];
        Console.WriteLine (reqWord);
```

i am getting `1]`  as result but i want whatever digit before last ] in a string

Comment: To be clear: You want the whole _number_ not just one _digit_. Right?

Comment: @Fildoryes i want whatever digit before last ]

Comment: What is that logic you are performing? *"i want whatever digit before last ] in a string"* - then something like `input.Split(' ', ']').Last(o => o.Length > 0)` will do.

Comment: @Pratex `whatever digit` contradicts `26`. That's a multi-digit number. So you want the last *number*, not just the last digit, 6. The regular expression `(\d+)\]$` would capture the last number in a group

Comment: `reqWord.Replace("]", "")` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using RegularExpressions you can write this

```
// Take the position of the last space
int pos = input.LastIndexOf(' ');

// Extract the number from that pos and remove the final ]
string number = input.Substring(pos).TrimEnd(']');

// Eventually convert it to an integer
Int32.TryParse(number, out int value);

Console.WriteLine(value);
```

This approach will get you the "whole number" before the "]", not the last digit. The last digit if your string ends with "...42]" is 2 not 42.

If your intention is to get just the last digit then it's just a matter to index the string to get the character from the string end minus 2

```
char digit = input[input.Length-2];
```

Of course to get a safe implementation of this logic you need to add a check about the string length

Answer (score 5):

You can parse the string using a regular expression, like this:

```cs
string input = "[XR] Z_Prem_4000+_Delphi_700+ [InstalmentScheme 1]";

var match = Regex.Match(input, @"(\d+)]$"); // gets the digits before ] at the end of the string
var reqWord = "";
if (match.Success)
{
    reqWord = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
Console.WriteLine(reqWord);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since a string implements `IEnumerable<Char>` you could also use a readable Linq query:

```
string lastNumber = String.Concat(input.Reverse().Skip(1).TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).Reverse());
```

So it skips the last character and takes all digits, uses `Reverse` twice because you want the last.

This might not be the most efficient approach but it is working, simple and safe, so it will not cause an exception no matter how long the string is or if there is a number at all.

Comment: also thought about reversing string and this monstrosity: https://dotnetfiddle.net/I4HB1E - not sure if it actually has lower allocations or not

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a version that's based on `Span`:

```cs
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = "[XR] Z_Prem_4000+_Delphi_700+ [InstalmentScheme 1]";
        Console.WriteLine(Extract(test).ToString());
        
        test = "[XR] Z_Prem_4000+_Delphi_700+ [InstalmentScheme 26]";
        Console.WriteLine(Extract(test).ToString());
        
        test = "[XR] Z_Prem_4000+_Delphi_700+ [InstalmentScheme ]";
        Console.WriteLine(Extract(test).ToString());
    }
    
    public static ReadOnlySpan<char> Extract( ReadOnlySpan<char> input )
    {
        var lastIndex = input.LastIndexOf(' ');
        if (lastIndex < 0) return "";
        
        return input[lastIndex..^1];
    }
}
```

See in action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7lt36B

Ouput

```
1
26
```

EDIT: previous version parsed to int, which isn't actually a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible solutions here (if not more):

1. Built-in string methods for manipulation [Split in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split) and [Substring in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-8.0). Your solution missed one step, where the last `]` needed to be removed. Here is the solution using that string methods:

```
        string input = "[XR] Z_Prem_4000+_Delphi_700+ [InstalmentScheme 1]";
        var words = input.Split(' ');
        var reqWord = "";
        if(words.Length > 1)
        {
            reqWord = words[words.Length - 1];
            Console.WriteLine(reqWord.Substring(0, reqWord.Length - 1));
        }
```

2. Using [Regular Expressions (Regex) in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-8.0) ([here is a quick regex reference in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#character-escapes)). Here is solution using regex syntax and grouping :

```
        string input = "[XR] Z_Prem_4000+_Delphi_700+ [InstalmentScheme 1]";
        Regex rx = new Regex(@"^\[[^\[]*\D*(\d*)\]$");
        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(input);
        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(matches[0].Groups[1].Value);
        }
```

In general, string methods can be used for simple problems and manipulations that aren't too complicated. Regex is much more powerful, as in theory it can handle any manipulation or sub-string extraction in a single line of code, but on the other hand the code readability is worsened, when using regular expressions. Learning both solution paths is the best, and learning regex in general can be a useful skill down the line, regardless of the programming language in use.